# Getting runtime values of formal arguments in R

Tags: r

I have a function with default arguments which just returns its arguments as a list:

```
x <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3){formals()}
```

and another function which is a simple wrapper around `x`

```
y <- function(a, ...) x(a, ...)
```

However, in function `x`, I would like to get the runtime values of the arguments, not the default values. So that,

```
y(a=3, b=4)
```

should return

```
$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 4

$c
[1] 3
```

and not

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

which is what I get now. Maybe one of sys.* functions might help, but I am not so experienced on these... Is there an easy way to call a function like formals() to get the values of the arguments specified by the caller?

Comment: I do not get it. In `x` you're in the function so you can access to the argument: `x <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3)list(a=a, b=b, c=c)`

Comment: List of arguments is very long in the real case, so I do not want to specify all of them both in arguments list and in the body of the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
x <- function(a=1, b=2, c=3) mget(names(formals()))
y <- function(a, ...) x(a, ...)

y(a=3, b=4)
#$a
#[1] 3
#
#$b
#[1] 4
#
#$c
#[1] 3
```

Comment: @gkcn if this answers your question, then you should accept and/or upvote it.